# Word for the feeling when you are looking for an solution

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrases

The title is kinda self-explanatory, but what I'm looking for is a one single word describing your desperate need/desire to find the solution of your problem/situation.

I'm writing a story where a character is cheated out of his price and I try to describe how he felt:

“But I… But he…!” stuttered Adam, a third bewildered, a third furious and a third [insert word here].

He feels cheated, confused and angry by what had just happen, but are desperately looking for a way he perhaps won or finding a way to dismiss whatever foul play he had been subjugated by, and I want to sum it up into one word that would match the sentence above.

I'm mot even sure that what I look for exist, but I have this gnawing sensation in the back of my neck that makes me suspect that it just might.

Comment: Is he *clutching at straws*?

Comment: Is he what at what???

Comment: Clutching at straws.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but no, he is not to my knowledge "clutching at straws"

Comment: @PotatoesAndPears - in that case, might he be [*grasping at straws*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clutch-grasp-at-straws?q=clutch%2Fgrasp+at+straws)?

Comment: Well, good to know. So, why you no just say "desperate"? You used that word to explain it to us. So use that word to explain it to others. (There are no dedicated words for "desperate for X" for each value of X. That is simply not how language works.)

Comment: Well after learning what "grasping at straws" means I can say it's about exactly what ! was looking for. 

“But I… But he…!” stuttered Adam, a third bewildered, a third furious and a third desperately grasping at straws.

I think it works quite well. Thank you guys!

Comment: "desperate for a solution"

Answer (score 1):

"Grasping/clutching at straws" was about exactly what I was looking for!
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clutch-grasp-at-straws?q=clutch%2Fgrasp+at+straws